# Как бэкапить всю систему centos 7 удаленно?

Tags: сервер, centos

Есть сервер. Установлена Centos 7. Есть доступ только удаленно по ssh. Надо бекапить всю систему чтобы потом можно было развернуть на другой железе. Посоветуйте как сделать? "Я сижу на Windows'e."

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90917/discussion-on-question-by-elaman-razakov-----centos-7-).

Comment: Но один комментарий я оставлю на видном месте: при отсутствии свободного места на диске неизбежна передача создаваемого бекапа на лету по сети каким-то способом. Есть вариант передавать создаваемый tar-архив через SSH-туннель, или borg-backup ранее упомянули, или краткий обзор по существующим программам для бекапа можно глянуть например тут https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Synchronization_and_backup_programs_(Русский) // И при создании бекапа работающей системы важно остановить всё, что можно остановить, чтобы в процессе создания бекапа файлы не изменялись и не сломали бекап